# Exclude files above certain size from download with smbclient

Tags: smbclient

I'm trying to download all files smaller than a certain size (a few megabytes) with smbclient. I have seen that it is possible to use the command mask from within smbclient to download files of a certain type. However is it also possible to exclude all files of a certain type? Alternatively is it possible to download all files smaller than a certain size?

I'm trying to download my lectures notes excluding all the lecture videos (which are several hundred megabytes in size)

Comment: What is your OS? Can you mount the share? I believe mounting the share will turn your problem into "exclude files above certain size while copying from one directory subtree to another". The new problem is general, not specific to SMB, Samba or `smbclient`. Standard tools can be used, they don't need to know anything about SMB. Solutions to exclude large files probably already exist. Have you tried this approach? Can you?

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu. It is an interesting approach I will look into it!